# Jupyter notebook not reading an existing file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have the exact same file directory but Jupyter Notebook is saying there is no such file or directory found.

Here is the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Macintosh HD/Users/kishanpatel/Documents/Machine Learning Data/train.zip'
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

When you seek help here it is helpful if you provide more details (e.g. How did you verify that Path) and formulate a question.

I am guessing you are trying to write an absolute path which starts with `/` on [MacOS](https://www.josharcher.uk/code/find-path-to-folder-on-mac/).

In your case it is maybe `/Users/kishanpatel/Documents/Machine Learning Data/train.zip`

Comment: I dragged the file into the terminal which gave the directory. This is what it printed:/Users/kishanpatel/Documents/Machine\ Learning\ Data/test.zip

Comment: However, when inserted into the directory into jupyter notebook it said it wasn't a directory.

Comment: `Machine\ Learning` is the problem. Try to avoid spaces in folder names.

Comment: I made another folder without spaces but it still gives the same error.

Comment: /Users/kishanpatel/Documents/MLDATA/test.zip

Comment: Try `import os; os.getcwd()` in your notebook

Comment: The same error showed up. This is the full error message.

Comment: NotADirectoryError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-40719067ea74> in <module>()
----> 1 train_data = create_train_data()

<ipython-input-58-ecf6307f9a86> in create_train_data()
      1 def create_train_data():
      2     train_data = []
----> 3     for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
      4         label = label_img(img)
      5         path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR,img)

NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/kishanpatel/Documents/MLDATA/test.zip'

Comment: Sorry that is just a bunch of text.

Comment: Oh I fixed the problem. I didn't unzip the file. Thanks!